# is php load whole file when we use fopen() command

Tags: php, fopen

I write an php script that help with limit speed and connections in download files. I used `fopen()` and `fseek()` something like this:

```
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
if($f){
    fseek($f,$start);//$start extracted from $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']
    while(!feof($f)){
        echo fread($f,$speed);//$speed is bytes per second
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

download process may take several hours to complete, is whole file be in memory until end of download? and how I can optimize this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `fread` uses an internal buffer to stream the data (8KB by default), so only a very small part of the file actually resides in memory.